# When Should I Call Write in Realm

Tags: realm

If I call write and update an object with a list of newly created other objects, will those objects automatically be written into Realm as well?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you will update a Realm Object inside a write transaction and that object has a one-to-many relationship to another Realm Object. Your class may look like this for example:

```
public class Owner: Object {
    let listOfObjects: List<SomeObject> = List<SomeObject>()
}
```

Then if you create a list of type SomeObject in a write block and set your class' listOfObjects to the newly created list, the new list of objects will be persisted in Realm when the write block ends. (Assuming your SomeObject class is a subclass of Object ofcourse)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding (in Realm Objective-C and Realm Swift at least), no. If you create a new list of objects that aren't persisted in Realm yet and assign them as child objects of an object that is, they still won't be guaranteed to be added to Realm that way.

For best practice, I recommend that in your write transaction, you both explicitly add the new objects to Realm and then add them to the child object list of that object.